# set checkbox to localStorage value in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, checkbox, local-storage

I seem to be unable to set the checked state of a checkbox with localStorage in Chrome.

Her's my test code.

```
<script>
function setStorage() {
localStorage.check = document.getElementById("bike").checked;
alert(localStorage.check);
}

</script>

<script>
function onLoaded() {
document.getElementById("bike").checked = localStorage.check
alert(localStorage.check)
}
</script>

<body onload="onLoaded()">
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike 
</form>
<button onclick="setStorage()">setStorage</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Only in chrome right ? which version of chrome ? Your code seems ok , working in both mozilla and chrome for me

Comment: Chrome 38.0.2125.122. You able to close the browser and reopen and the checked state persists? I'm stumped. It work perfect in Firefox for me. In Chrome I'm also able to use web storage fine for other inputs just not checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
localStorage.setItem("bike", document.getElementById("bike").checked)
```

and you can retrieve the value by

```
localStorage.getItem("bike")
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here's the code.

```
<script>
function setStorage() {


localStorage.check = document.getElementById("bike").checked;
alert(localStorage.check);


}

</script>
<script>
function onLoaded() {
if (localStorage.check == 'true') {
document.getElementById("bike").checked = true;
alert("so far so good");
}
}


</script>


<body onload="onLoaded()">
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike 
</form>
<button onclick="setStorage()">setStorage</button>
```